# strange error when reload tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a very general table view.

when it is refreshed, it will go to fetch list of objects from Parse. Analyze these data in a dispatch_async queue, then refresh table view. Most time, it has no problem, but some time reloadData() crash

[image]

Is it crashes because the tableView is reloading data when I call it? (when the tableview is init, reloadData may be called automatically) How to avoid this error? ( there is no error message in console )

**EDIT:**
I tries to put `?`, but does not work

[image]

Comment: I think adding/deleting cells is update UI

Comment: Are you deallocating the table view before reloading?

Comment: @JAL nope, this function is in UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your tableView (or whatever object you're sending the message to) is nil. So sometime before your async call dispatched this on the main queue, your tableView got dealloacted.

Check this link out for some info:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

Comment: But this is written in UITableViewController, isn't they guarantee tableView is not nil? And swift will make the var to be optional when it is possible to be nil

Comment: OK, I just re-read over your post, and see that you think it may be because it's calling it while the tableView is reloading still, try delaying that reloadData by a second and see if that fixes the issue (to give the tableView time to finish reloading before calling reloadData.) If that still gives the same error, I'd then check to see if possibly you're deallocating the UITableViewController, or are somehow instantiating a new one to cause this one to be deallocated, because this only really gets called when you're sending messages to objects which don't exist in the heap.

Comment: I tried call "reloadData()" multiple time, either the first call crash or none. So, my assumption is wrong. When I remove the main_queue, there seems no error happens

Comment: So when you just call it directly on the main queue instead of dispatching it? Does it need to be dispatched? It seems your just dispatching it asynchronously, and then using that to immediately call it on the main_queue, why not just call it on the main queue to begin with?

Comment: because I have to fetch it from server and then do "post = fetchedObjects". they are run in another queue

Answer (score 0):

You will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error mostly in the following scenarios:

You are trying to access an object that is not initialized.

You are trying to access an object that no longer exists. Either it’s being released or it’s nil. In ARC mode, make sure you take ownership of the object that you want to use.
You are passing an message to an object that the object doesn’t understand.

It can also happen for bad typecast. Like the lines below where I am trying to access an int with %@ in stead of %d.

```
 int myAwesomeInt = 9;
 NSLog(@"%@", myAwesomeInt);
```

How to debug:

Identify what you did that caused the crash. Did it crash while view of a particular view controller didLoad or in a delegate method or on a particular action. That will often help to find the object that is casuing the error.

(In your case look at what specifically happens when you are reloading the table. Do a stack trace line by line and see what your code is doing during a reload)

Most of the time “NSZombies” can help to identify the dead object. You can enable NSZombies by editing your scheme Product -> Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics.

If you still don’t find the root cause then always go backwards from child view controller to parent view controller to see what object needs to be retained or what message needs to be passed properly.
Look into Static Analyzer and Instruments for advanced debugging.

Credit:
[The Basic Troubleshooting guide](http://subhb.org/2012/07/02/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-error/)

Hope this helps. Good Luck

Comment: The crash happens when I start run the app, and tableView start loading. So: 1. I believe UITableViewController guarantee tableView exist, 2. there is no way I can deallocate self.tableView. 3. reloadData() should be understand

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you replace the self.tableview with an NSLog statement? That might tell us something if the NSLog still has the same error.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow